# Anyone know how conversions are recorded by FB pixel extension?

Tags: extensions, facebook

I have a Facebook ad running, and via the magic of the pixel, I can see that our website got a conversion today. Hooray! When I look at our Magento orders, though, I see a transaction yesterday but nothing placed today. However, yesterday's order did get *invoiced* today. This makes me wonder at which point the extension triggers the conversion so that we see it in Facebook. As soon as the order is in the system (at which point it's still processing) or only after it's technically complete on our end?

As a marketing person who knows nothing of coding or how Magento sends data, I kind of just want reassurance that we're seeing a real, completed conversion (especially since there's no means of cross-checking, like with a transaction ID or $ amount). I think my explanation is perfectly logical but does anyone know for sure?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

to be able to view when your facebook pixel fires you can use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-pixel-helper/fdgfkebogiimcoedlicjlajpkdmockpc?hl=en

this will show you your:
Pageview
AddtoCart
initiatecheckout

and any other data you are passing to facebook on any of the pages your have your pixel set up be it your product page, your cart your checkout or your success